# SELECT same data from EITHER one of two tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, mariadb

I have to do a bit of time-keeping. Some employees are part of the first team and some are part of the second team. I need to display a simple table of who signed in and when along with some other basic information.

If both tables team1 and team2 have the same columns (`first_name`, `last_name` and `date`) though it's absolutely guaranteed that only one of those tables will return data per row how do I avoid using a bunch of aliases (`first_name AS team1_first_name`) and just always have SQL return `first_name`?

An example query:

```
SELECT *
FROM associates AS ac
LEFT JOIN team1 AS t1 ON (t1.id = ac.team1) 
LEFT JOIN team2 AS t2 ON (t2.id = ac.team2) 
ORDER BY ac.date DESC LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: I think you can use union with distinct. And when you make left join team2 you need change your "on" (t2.id = ac.team2).

Comment: In `associates` do you have only 1 foreign key `team1` for both tables or is it a typo?

Comment: @evilGenius I'll look in to that.

Comment: @forpas I figured I would miss something minor, typo.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Already received a working answer, thank you nonetheless. Basically `SELECT` the exact same data/columns from two different tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since one of `t1.first_name` and `t2.first_name` is null and the other is not, 
you can use [`coalesce()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in the select statement like this:

```
select
  coalesce(t1.first_name, t2.first_name) first_name,
  coalesce(t1.last_name, t2.last_name) last_name,
  .............................................
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to type in all the columns and employees are on only one team, you can `union` the tables before the `join`:

```
SELECT a.*, t.*
FROM associates a JOIN
     ((SELECT t1.* FROM team1 t1) UNION ALL
      (SELECT t2.* FROM team2 t2)
     ) t
     ON t.id IN (ac.team1, ac.team2)
ORDER BY a.date DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

Comment: @John . . . This is a different from the other answer.  In particular, this does exactly what your question requests -- "how do I avoid using a bunch of aliases".

Comment: True, unfortunately not every table pair can `UNION ALL` since the pair I was working with contained a different number of columns; a clarification I was not aware of that I should have made originally. Both answers are excellent and clarify an important context which is why I up-voted yours. Thank you!